# Filtering gallery based on current user

Tags: filter, powerapps

I have a gallery of draft items that I am trying to filter based on the login of the current user and uses email address from the Created By column, which is set to people or group, and does not have multiple choices in the SharePoint list - I only want the current user to see ONLY their draft items, and no one else's.  The draft items show up if I'm filtering based on status, but as soon as I add the filter of the current user, it doesn't work. The `ThisUser` variable is populating with the logged in user.  Here are my codes:

```
APP: OnStart: Set(ThisUser, User().Email)
GALLERY ITEMS: Filter('SP List Name', Status.Value="Draft", 'Created By'.Email=ThisUser)
```

I've tried many options with no luck.  I'm able to see the list of drafts if I take out the line in the Filter function that has to do with email...as soon as I add the email line back in, the gallery is blank.

Comment: I would check to see what `ThisUser` equals. Add a label anywhere and set its Text to `ThisUser`. Also in your Gallery add a similar label set to `ThisItem.'Created By'.Email` - hopefully this will help you identify the issue. Your filter formula looks okay. One other thing, how many items are there in your list?

Comment: How many total items are there in the list? Are you getting any delegation warning in your formula? Try adding indexing on Status and Created By column, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of User().Email, use Office365Users.MyProfileV2().

You will need to add the Office365Users connection to your app as well.

So in your OnStart, set a current user variable

```
Set(ThisUser, Office365Users.MyProfileV2());
```

In your gallery, use that variable to filter your list

```
Filter(
    'SP List Name', 
    Status.Value = "Draft", 
    'Created By'.Email = ThisUser.mail
)
```

Sometimes the result of User().Email and Office365Users.MyProfileV2().mail will be different and that's why your code won't always work

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  This solved the issue that I had with people with email aliases as their preferred email not being able to see their drafts.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help out!

Comment: It happens for me too so that's when I found that out. Glad it worked!